# compare two strings with .equals() don't work

Tags: java, android, string, compare, equals

I get a string form a list and try to compare it with some strings in the values and then do some stuff

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfList; i++){

    String LIST_TITLE;

    LIST_TITLE = list_title.get(i); //the List list_title includes some strings

    if(LIST_TITLE.equals(R.string.percentbattery)) {
        //do stuff
        Log.d("EQUAL!","" + LIST_TITLE);
    } else if(LIST_TITLE.equals(R.string.screenrecorder) == true) {
        //do stuff
        Log.d("EQUAL!","" + LIST_TITLE);
    } else if(LIST_TITLE.equals(R.string.eightsms) == true) {
        //do stuff
        Log.d("EQUAL!","" + LIST_TITLE);
    } else {
        // do stuff
        Log.e("TITLE NOT EQUAL","" + LIST_TITLE);
    }
}
```

If I compare my LIST_TITLE with the (R.string. ...) in my Logcat they are equal, but I get only the "TITLE NOT EQUAL" Log from the else statement.

Is there another way to compare these strings? the "==" method also don't work.

Comment: `if (condition == true)` is considered as bad style. It is easy to make mistake where you use `=` instead of `==` which means you are assigning `true` to `condition` (if it is variable). That is why it is better to just use `if (condition)` or if you really must compare it with `true` then use yoda style `if (true == condition)` - here even if you use `=` instead of `==` you will get compilation error because we can assign value to variables, not to other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.string.percentbattery` is not a String, it's an Integer that is the ID to reference the string.

what u want is:

```
LIST_TITLE.equals(context.getResources.getString(R.string.percentbattery))
```

Comment: Even if I use your solution or `LIST_TITLE.equals("String")` it doesn't work.
More details: I use this in an `AsyncTask (doInBackground)`. I fetch titles from a website and save them in a `List list_title`.
Now I try to compare this list_title with some strings to set an icon.
In this AsyncTask I have no context, so I used your solution without context. `LIST_TITLE.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.percentbattery))`
Could this be the mistake? Thanks

Comment: How exactly you call it makes no different. If inside an `Activity` you can call `getString(int)` without anything else. That really where this code is. The important to fix your code is to understand that `R.string.anything` is NOT a String, so you can't compare it with one, you need to get the actual string to be able to compare it.

Answer (score 2):

```
LIST_TITLE.equals(R.string.percentbattery)
```

This is incorrect, because you're trying to compare string with resource ID
You should get the string from resource first:

```
LIST_TITLE.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.percentbattery))
```

Comment: wow! four more answers while typing... I'm typing too slowly :)

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.xxx` is an `int`. You need to get the `String` from that `res`

Something like

```
if(LIST_TITLE.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.percentbattery)))
```

This is assuming you have `Activity Context` available. Otherwise, you would need to add a `Context` variable in front of `getResources()`

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.some_id` is just an integer by which you can get the String from the resources.
So in order to compare `Strings` correctly in you case you have to do:

```
String precentBattery = getResources().getString(R.string.percentbattery);
if (LIST_TITLE.equals (percentBattery)) ...
```